# Merging two csv files with panda.concat

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to merge two csv files using pandas.concat(). These files have the same row and columns structure and I would like to merge one after the other along the rows. For example, the first csv file ('ex1.csv') is

```
Ex1,Ex1
Ex1,Ex1
Ex1,Ex1
Ex1,Ex1
```

and the second ('ex2.csv') is

```
Ex2,Ex2
Ex2,Ex2
Ex2,Ex2
Ex2,Ex2
```

I would like the following output ('merged.csv')

```
Ex1,Ex1
Ex1,Ex1
Ex1,Ex1
Ex1,Ex1
Ex2,Ex2
Ex2,Ex2
Ex2,Ex2
Ex2,Ex2
```

This should be very simple... I have followed the documentation of pandas.concat() and several tutorial on the internet but I still don't get what I want. I have saved the csv files in the same directory where my script is. This is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

joined_files = os.path.join(".", "*.csv")
joined_list = glob.glob(joined_files)

li=[]
for filename in joined_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0,sep=',')
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(frame)
```

which returns the following output

```
>>> print(frame)
   Ex1 Ex1.1  Ex2 Ex2.1
0  Ex1   Ex1  NaN   NaN
1  Ex1   Ex1  NaN   NaN
2  Ex1   Ex1  NaN   NaN
3  NaN   NaN  Ex2   Ex2
4  NaN   NaN  Ex2   Ex2
5  NaN   NaN  Ex2   Ex2
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=None, sep=',')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column names are same..

```
dfnew = pd.concat([df1,df2]).reset_index(drop=true)
```